# Ethernet 100Base-TX vs T4

Tags: standards, ethernet

I keep reading docuemnts, but I do not understand between Ethernet 100Base-TX and T4.
According to this webpage : http://www.ybet.be/hardware2_ch4/hard2_ch4.php (sorry it's in french, but only look at the figures), the difference resides in the wiring of crossover cables. However, Ethernet 100Base-TX and T4 use the same RJ-45 cable. This is what I do not get.

Ethernet 100Base-TX and T4 are standard and they are not suppose to rely on differents cables, but the connections of wires in the figure troubles me.

Thank you for the answer!
Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

100BASE-T4 devices are extremely rare, practically everything Fast Ethernet is 100BASE-TX. -T4 uses one dedicated pair for each direction and switches the remaining two pairs as required to send - the data stream is split into three lanes. A port can only either send or receive, so it's all half-duplex. In contrast, 100BASE-TX uses only two pairs, one for each direction.

For a crossover connection (MDI to MDI or MDI-X to MDI-X), 100BASE-TX requires those two pairs (1-2 and 3-6) to be crossed while 100BASE-T4 requires all pairs to be crossed (1-2 with 3-6 and 4-5 with 7-8). Check IEEE 802.3 Clause 23.7.2 for details.